# How many matches can be made

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Two schools should play one against the other table tennis. Five students represent each of
these schools. Doubles should only play. Each pair from one school should play against
each pair from the other school just once. Each student should play.

A) 10 Matches B) 20 Matches C) 30 Matches
D) 40 Matches E) 50 Matches

how should i proceed to answer this question using combinations or permutations. I can make pairs manually and check them but that will be tedious and cumbersome task.

Comment: You need to show some work. You can't say that other than enumerating all possibilities you can't think of anything. Maybe you can't reach a conclusion, but you need to show what you have done and where you are stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think answer is D) 40 Matchers

Because there are two schools A and B, school B has five students, since doubles should only plays, school B can have at most C(5,2)=10 different teams.

Student a in school A can make 4 different teams with other students from school A, thus student a will play 4*10 matches.

Comment: Pl don't answer "no effort" questions.